# roscore giving error on WSL machine

Tags: ros, roscore, ros-indigo, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have WSL (windows subsystem for linux) on my windows  PC and I've been trying to follow the instructions given in the tutorial [here - ROS wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes) - I'm using ROS indigo version. As per the instruction in the tutorial when I try typing

> $ roscore

I get the following traceback error

> ... logging to
> /home/bchander/.ros/log/3ccbc5ec-2406-11e7-8358-562737a1c771/roslaunch-BHANUCHAND-632.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage.
> This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to
> interrupt Done checking log file disk
> usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server
> http://localhost:53878/ ros_comm
> version 1.11.21
>
> ## SUMMARY
>
> PARAMETERS  * /rosdistro: indigo  *
> /rosversion: 1.11.21
>
> NODES
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/**init**.py", line 307, in main
> p.start()
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 279, in start
> self.runner.launch()
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 654, in launch
> self._setup()
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 630, in _setup
> self._launch_master()
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 394, in _launch_master
> validate_master_launch(m, self.is_core, self.is_rostest)
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 83, in validate_master_launch
> if not rosgraph.network.is_local_address(m.get_host()):
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 176, in is_local_address
> local_addresses = ['localhost'] + get_local_addresses()
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 219, in get_local_addresses
> for iface in netifaces.interfaces():
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

What could be the possible solution for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259479/roscore-giving-error-on-wsl-machine/) by [bhanu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22691/bhanu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q238646.

You're likely not running a recent Win10 (Insider) build.

Btw: running ROS on WSL is really very experimental at the moment. Personally I would not use it for anything apart from some experimenting perhaps.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1